# I got "Warning: Error in kmeans: more cluster centers than distinct data points." How I fix it?

Tags: r, shiny, k-means, shinydashboard

I'm trying to fix my code but i get Warning: Error in kmeans: more cluster centers than distinct data points. when i run it. how I fix it? My references is from R Shiny gallery itself (https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/kmeans-example.html) but the differences is my shiny need to upload a file into it.

I'm using R under 3.5.3 version

```
res_clusters <- reactive({req(df_kmeans_selected())
      req(input$n_clusters)
      kmeans(
        df_kmeans_selected(),
        centers = input$n_clusters
      )
    })

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  req(df_kmeans_selected())
  req(res_clusters())
  palette(c(
    "#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
    "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"
  ))
  par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
  plot(df_kmeans_selected(),
       col = res_clusters()$cluster,
       pch = 20,
       cex = 1
  )
  points(res_clusters()$centers,
         pch = 4,
         cex = 1,
         lwd = 3
```

I expected k-means graphics can show up but failed. I show you my data from excel [This is my data. total 30 data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fglig.png)

Comment: are all variables numeric? Check that first. The best way would be to provide some sample data with `dput`.

Comment: Some variables numeric and character. I got eror in server.R. i'm new in R and still get confused

Comment: `kmeans` calculates the euclidean distance of data points. This is not possible for strings. Exclude these variables from your dataset.